# Struts2 populating form data results in array for Map<String, Object>

Tags: arrays, forms, jsp, struts2, ognl

Action class

```
public class ProductAction extends ActionSupport implements Preparable {
    private Document product;
}
```

Model

```
public class Document {
    private Map<String, Object> properties;
}
```

JSP

```
<s:textfield name="product.properties.PRODUCT_NAME" 
             value="%   {product.properties..PRODUCT_NAME}" 
             label="%{getText('label.PRODUCT_NAME')}" size="40" />

<s:textfield name="product.properties.SUPPLIER" 
             value="%{product.properties.SUPPLIER}" 
             label="%{getText('label.SUPPLIER')}" size="40" />
```

Product_name and Supplier are populated as Array in Map (`Map<String, String[]>`) properties.

```
PRODUCT_NAME : [Ljava.lang.String;@4e96ac47]
SUPPLIER     : [Ljava.lang.String;@1c90a278]
```

If I change the Document->properties to `Map<String, String>` it works fine.

But I want to retain Document->properties as `Map<String, Object>` because of other datatypes.

How to solve this issue, I want form data to be populated as `String` instead of `String[]`.

I don't have multiple text fields with the same name.

Comment: what do you want to display, the key or the value.

Comment: Learn how to use indexed properties in struts2.

Comment: I want to pass private Map<String, Object> properties to dao layer for save, but Map<String, String[]> array is causing an issue where dao layer accepts only Map<String, String>

Comment: Why are you holding different data types in the same map?

Comment: Because it is the easiest way to process data, where I can have date, string, integer, etc

Comment: And how will you convert submitted values to date, string, integer, etc?

Comment: Dao layer will take care of it based on the meta data.

Comment: Form JSP to action? DAO? Really?

Comment: http://struts.apache.org/release/2.3.x/docs/type-conversion.html#TypeConversion-ApplyingaTypeConvertertoabeanormodel
above link has the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution: we can apply type Converter to a bean or model 
http://struts.apache.org/release/2.3.x/docs/type-conversion.html#TypeConversion-ApplyingaTypeConvertertoabeanormodel

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<s:textfield name="product.properties.SUPPLIER" 
             value="%{product.properties.SUPPLIER[0]}" 
             label="%{getText('label.SUPPLIER')}" size="40" />
```

This will retrieve the first item in the Array

Comment: Thanks for the reply.
I have no issues in jsp, but the actual problem is I don't want array in action Map<String, Object>.

Answer (score 0):

Modify the model and introduce methods to work with Map but save the data to the underlying Map like below

```
public class Document {
    private Map<String, Object> properties;


    public Map<String, String> getStringProperties() {
        //logic to populate Map<String, String>
        return new HashMap<String, String>();
    }

    public void setStringProperties(Map<String, String> stringProperties) {
        properties.putAll(stringProperties);
    }
}
```

In the jsp use stringProperties like below

```
<s:textfield name="product.stringProperties.SUPPLIER" 
             value="%{product.stringProperties.SUPPLIER}" 
             label="%{getText('label.SUPPLIER')}" size="40" />
```

Comment: http://struts.apache.org/release/2.3.x/docs/type-conversion.html#TypeConversion-ApplyingaTypeConvertertoabeanormodel

Answer (score 0):

Using [Element annotation](https://struts.apache.org/docs/element-annotation.html) is much easier than writing `TypeConverter` for this.

```
@Element( value = java.lang.String.class )
private Map<String, Object> properties;
```